# How to select region on image and extract pixel values in numbers of that particular region?

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I want to select a rectangular region on the image using mouse events and extract the pixel values within the rectangle as a list or an array or a tuple but not an image crop that returns a cropped image. I have found no way of how to achieve this.

Does anyone know any way of achieving this or any tips or suggestions?

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: `selectROI`. and no, you don't want to "draw" a rectangle. that's not the goal. you want to select a rectangular region interactively.

Comment: ok thank you for the suggestion I will also modify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to use is [`cv.selectROI`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga2e2256794d0c88f4cfc4fdd7890c9794)

It can take different arguments. The simplest case is just taking an image (numpy array). Here's an example where also the window name is specified.

Personally I also prefer to use the `fromCenter` argument.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile("lena.jpg"))

bbox = cv.selectROI("lena", im, fromCenter=True)
cv.destroyWindow("lena")

print("region:", bbox)

(x,y,w,h) = bbox

subregion = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv.imshow("lena subregion", subregion)
cv.waitKey(-1)
cv.destroyWindow("lena subregion")
```

Comment: OpenCV's `imread` should be able to read .tif images *already*. if not, there's the [`tifffile` package](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) that handles very large TIFF files efficiently. `skimage.io` seems able to use that package as well.

Comment: yes, it does read my tif images, OpenCV reads the image but it can't perform its methods like select ROI and some other ones that's why I asked.

Comment: you should open a new question then, and supply all information